# SignalR server application on the Azure virutally

Tags: azure, signalr, signalr-hub

I try to run self-hosted SignalR server application, the server on the Azure virutally

```
const string ServerURI = "http://<myip>:8080";

SignalR = WebApp.Start(ServerURI);
```

The server is not created.

If you create a local server then all is well

```
const string ServerURI = "http://localhost:8080";
```

An inbound port rule is created.

On a separate VPS everything works fine, but on Azure is not...

Comment: Are you hosting the site on an App Service Plan or a VM?

Comment: Virtual Machine

Comment: When you say "An inbound port rule is created", do you mean a binding in IIS or a rule in the VM's NSG?

Comment: Rule in the VM's Firewall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you provision a new VM, Azure adds a default Network Security Group (think of it as a firewall) that allows RDP traffic (TCP port 3389) from any connection and denies all traffic going to your VM on any other port.

Since you want port 8080 to be accessible from the outside, you will need to add an NSG rule that explicitly allows port 8080 in.

Documentation on how to add an NSG rule on an existing NSG:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-create-nsg-arm-pportal#create-rules-in-an-existing-nsg